# Matlab's `mdwtdec()` Vs Python's `wavedec()`

Tags: wavelet, wavelet-transform

I am trying to convert a Matlab code into Python. To do a Multisignal 1-D wavelet decomposition I use [`mdwtdec()`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/mdwtdec.html?requestedDomain=in.mathworks.com) in Matlab. The closest function I found in python is in `pywt` lib, [`wavedec()`](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/ref/dwt-discrete-wavelet-transform.html#multilevel-decomposition-using-wavedec).

While the matlab function take 4 arguments `mdwtdec(DIRDEC,X,LEV,WNAME)`: here `X` is the signal, `LEV` is the level, `WNAME` is the wavelet name and `DIRDEC` is Direction indicator: `r` (row) or `c` (column).

`mdwtdec(DIRDEC,X,LEV,WNAME)` returns the wavelet decomposition at level `LEV` of each row (if `DIRDEC = r`) or each column (if `DIRDEC = c`) of matrix `X`, using the wavelet `WNAME.`

In pywavelets, `wavedec(X,LEV,WNAME)` takes `X`, `LEV` and `WNAME` similar to Matlab. There is no option for the direction, so by default it is set to 'r'. I need 'c' as an option too, How do I achieve it in Python?

Answer (score 1):

`pywt`'s `wavedec` assumes that the signal is an array. If the signal isn't an array, then the results are less convincing (for square matrices the result appears to correspond to a rowwise operation, but the same cannot be said for non-square matrices).

Fortunately you can run `wavedec` for each row or column using [`numpy`'s `apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html). With a little bit of extra wrapping, you can define a Matlab approximation (Matlab's version probably has better error handling) to `mdwtdec` such as:

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
def mdwtdec(dirdec,x,lev,wavelet):
    """
    Multisignal 1D Discrete Wavelet decomposition.

    Parameters
    ----------
    dirdec  : char
        Direction indicator: 'r' (row) or 'c' (column)
    x       : matrix
        Input matrix
    wavelet : Wavelet object or name string
        Wavelet to use
    lev     : int
        Decomposition level (must be >= 0). If level is None then it
        will be calculated using the ``dwt_max_level`` function.
    """
    return np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda y: np.concatenate(pywt.wavedec(y, wavelet, level=lev)),
        axis={'c':0, 'r':1}[dirdec], arr=x)
```

in which I've used:

- `np.concatenate` to keep the approximation and details coefficients as a tight row/column vector
- a `lambda` expression to specify the executed function along with the mapping of input arguments

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it out with 2D matrices, It works for `dirdec = 'r'` But for `dirdec = 'c'` it raises `ValueError: axis must be less than arr.ndim; axis=0, rank=0.`

Comment: What I have done is to transpose the input `x` to `wavedec` for a `dirdec = 'c'` processing. It works decently, but the output vary in both size (sometimes) and values from matlab's `mdwtdec()`, which is what is making me doubt if I am doing this wrong.

Comment: My tests results looked ok for `dirdec='c'` with `np.matrix` inputs. Mind providing a sample test case you're having problems with?

Comment: I tried ```p = np.random.rand(512, 7608)
    q = mswpd.mdwtdec('c', p, 1, 'db4')```

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce this error (other than for the trivial scalar input which does indeed have 0 rank). Note sure how you'd get a 0-rank matrix (with a 512x7608 input) in `mdwtdec` from my post.